# How does Rdio.com do their anchor based hyperlinks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When you visit http://www.rdio.com/#/aboutus/ for instance you will see that their about us page loads, now when you hover over or inspect the "About Us" link in their footer, it simply points to /aboutus. I have also checked View Source and there is strictly no magic occuring on the link itself.

I am thinking jQuery must update all their `<A>` elements and replace with the anchor based hash tag url approach.

How would I get this to function in my own project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The anchors are there for linking; the real magic is Ajax and other dynamic JavaScript-based content. Here's what the link might look like:

```
$('.some-link').click(function(e) {
    // Allow for linking:
    window.location.hash = '#/' + this.getAttribute('href');

    // Start loading the content:
    $.ajax({
        // ...
        success: function() {
            // New content gets put in
        }
    });

    // Prevent the real link from being followed:
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: That's interesting, thanks minitech, I actually tried e.preventDefault() and a click event just like this, but it still brought up the link as well as firing my event which was odd, let me try again.

Comment: lol ok it's working! It helped if I actually passed `e` in the function parameter ;) Thanks for your help!